# Issue with Global Describe get vs containsKey when using namespace and Execute Anon vs Apex

Tags: apex, describesobject, namespace, execute-anonymous, describefieldresult

Ok, so a different spin here to this: [Issue with GlobalDescribe Field Results and Managed Package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70207/issue-with-globaldescribe-field-results-and-managed-package)

I do not think it should be doing this...

When executing via the execute anonymous in dev console:

```
system.debug(logginglevel.error,Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ns__objname').getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('ns__status__c'));
```

I get:

> 10:24:02.090 (90175202)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|ERROR|true

Now with this method in an apex class executed from the dev console:

```
public static void testit(){
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    138. system.debug(logginglevel.error,gd.get('ns__objname').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('ns__status__c')); 
    139. system.debug(logginglevel.error,gd.get('ns__objname').getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('ns__status__c'));     
}
```

I get:

> 10:24:02.205 (205647072)|USER_DEBUG|[138]|ERROR|ns__Status__c
>
> 10:24:02.205 (205965311)|USER_DEBUG|[139]|ERROR|false

Note: ns__objname replaced the actual value and yes the values typed are the same and I attempted both with `ns_status__c` AND `ns__Status__c`

So:

1. In execute anonymous the describe shows the field map **does** contain the key for the field name with the namespace
2. when the apex code is executed it shows:

   - on get - the value is returned
   - on containsKey the result is false (even though a get returns the field)

What the heck is going on. Why does execute anon show it contains the key and the apex method shows it does not. And why does a get return a value when the containsKey does not?

**Repro**

1. Create a new DE org and add a namespace
2. Create an object and add some fields
3. Use the above code to see for yourself.

**Workaround**

instead of using containsKey simply do a get and check for null

I believe this is a bug. Am I wrong? Anyone from SF listening as this is a PITA

Comment: looks a bug to me ..

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - k. Hoping someone from SF sees this because I refuse to go through the pain of attempting to open a ticket nor do I have the weeks to spend getting it to the proper place before it gets closed....