# Sobject put set value of managed field in case of same field api name as unmanaged field

Tags: managed-package, sobject, sobjectfield, dynamic-apex

We are developing a managed package that contains a custom object and a REST API to do CRUD operation on that object. We are not using standard salesforce REST API for valid business reasons.

In this REST API we allow user to set value of field on custom object that are part of managed package as well unmanaged field that they may create after package installation. Field that are part of package will be qualified by namespace prefix.

We are facing a issue that may be a platform bug. Here is situation.

1. Let's assume we have a field with API name `FirstName__c` and namespace is `abc` so fully qualified field name will be `abc__FirstName__c`.
2. After package installation customer creates another field with same API name(`FirstName__c`) which is perfectly valid as namespace prefix make them unique.
3. Through our API user can pass a map of name-value pair, where key is API name of field and value is field value.
4. Within API we use this map to set value of field by using [`SObject.put(fieldname, value)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put) method. FieldName is string and value is Object type casted dynamically by checking type of field using describe call.
5. Problem that we are facing is that if user pass field name as `FirstName__c`, `sObject.put()` method sets value of packaged field i.e. `abc_FirstName__c` not `FirstName__c`

Comment: See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70207/issue-with-globaldescribe-field-results-and-managed-package/70208 for same issue and Discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SObject.put(fieldName, value)
```

This method is an overloaded method. It has two definitions:

- fieldName is of **string** type
- fieldName is of **Schema.SObjectField** type.

The first definition of this method will not work for you but the second definition of this will definitely work for you.

```
Schema.SObjectField field = Schema.sObjectType.<object_api_name>.fields.getMap().get(<field_api_name);
record.put(field, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are setting the field `FirstName__c` from within the Managed Package, the managed package will always assume that you are wanting to set the field `abc__FirstName__c` rather than the unmanaged `FirstName__c`. I don't know as I'd call this a bug, but it is certainly known behaviour.