# Update non-managed custom field when it exists

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-field

In my managed package I have a custom field on the Opportunity called `Interest_Rate__c`. Since it is in the managed package it has my package prefix so like `my_Namespace__Interest_Rate__c`.

As part of my package there is a UI to select which field to populate with data. The default is to populate `my_Namespace__Interest_Rate__c` but it allows the user to select a different field if they want to.

However, a test user of the package already has a custom field called `Interest_Rate__c` that they created manually for some other use outside of what my package does so there is no prefix. Since they already have the field and are using it for other things they would like my managed package to update the `Interest_Rate__c` that they manually created. Even if they select to populate the field they created it still populates the field in the package. However, if they map to a custom field that they created that doesn't match a field name in my package like `Interest_Rate_2__c` then their manually created field gets updated by my package.

If there are two fields with the same name, one with my package prefix and one without (manually created) is Apex forcing the use of the managed package version of the field or am I missing something? If so is there a way to use the exact name? Nothing in my code is forcing the namespace prefix.

I looked for Salesforce documentation on this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: We've come across this as well and didn't find a way around it.  Because we manage our customer's orgs, we just have a naming convention in subscriber org to make sure we never have this problem.

Comment: @NickCook is there anything in the Salesforce documentation that explicitly states that? I'm working on this for work (relatively new to Salesforce development) and I'd like to report back to management.

Comment: This has been a known issue with ISVs since the very beginning of Managed Packages. The design intent is to not have subscriber's fields interfere with the manage package fields (and vice versa). The downside is that there's no way for a managed package to access subscriber fields of the same name.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the explanation. Is there anything in official documentation that states this? I'd like to provide it to management at the company I work for.

Comment: @James  I'm not aware of any official documentation on this.  Have you tried what's in this other question?  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133977/sobject-put-set-value-of-managed-field-in-case-of-same-field-api-name-as-unmanag?rq=1