# Can't query local fields from within a Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-field

My managed package has a field, let's say, `mypackage__field__c`.
The Org where this package is installed has a field called `field__c`.

The problem is that I can't access the Org's `field__c` field from package's Apex code:

```
System.debug( lead.field__c ); // returns the value of mypackage__field__c
System.debug( lead.get('field__c') ); // also returns the value of mypackage__field__c
```

How do I access the `field__c` field from my Apex code?

Comment: What does [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap) show as the keyset? I suspect  if you queried for the sObject with SOQL you wouldn't have access to both fields due to Shadowing. See Idea: [Support Dynamic SOQL "No Shadowing" Option](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E0bnAAC)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is no solution to this problem: it's the penalty for the great convenience of being able to leave out the namespace prefix for managed package fields referenced within the managed package. (And I presume a fix has never made it high enough up Salesforce's priority list.)

The workaround is to ensure that additional fields added after the package is installed are distinct in name ignoring the namespace e.g. give the field the API name of `localfield__c`; its label can still be left as "Field".

Comment: For better understanding why that has been done by Salesforce-- following links may be checked -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70207/issue-with-globaldescribe-field-results-and-managed-package, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27959/describesobjectresult-missing-fields-when-executed-in-managed-package